# Bold text value if field value contains Dec

Tags: reporting-services

I am looking to `BOLD` the text value if the Field value contains the Dec.

I am using this in the expression.

```
=IIF(instr(Fields!Dateperiod.Value, "Dec"),"Bold",Fields!DatePeriod.Value)
```

I have added this expression to the Textbox `FontWeight` property.

It doesn't seem to do anything and no errors.

Could someone tell me where I may be going wrong. 
thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the Dec string in a date field?. Also see this, if the field doesn't contain `Dec` string you are returning a date, a date is not a valid value for the FontWeight property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
IIF(InStr(Fields!Dateperiod.Value, "Dec") > 0,"Bold","Normal")
```

A quick test worked for me.